# Random Password Generator JavaScript

Tags: javascript, math, random

I am using window prompts and window.confirm to ask the user if they want to use certain characters in their password. (I know I can do checkboxes with some HTML, but this must be JS). 
How do I pass the confirm answers to the function and then use `Math.floor(Math.random() * length)`?

```
const key_strings = {
    lowercase: 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz',
    uppercase: 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ',
    number: '0123456789',
    symbol: " !"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\]^_`{|}~",
};

function generatePassword() {
  passwordCharSet = "";

  var length = window.prompt("Enter a number from 8 to 128 for password length.");

  var lowercase = window.confirm("Would you like to use lowercase letters?");
    if (lowercase == true) {
        passwordCharSet += lowercase;
    };

  var uppercase = window.confirm("Would you like to use uppercase letters?");
    if (uppercase == true) {
        passwordCharSet += uppercase;
    };

  var symbols = window.confirm("Would you like to use symbols?");
    if (symbols == true) {
        passwordCharSet += symbols;
    };

  var numbers = window.confirm("Would you like to use numbers?");
    if (numbers == true) {
        passwordCharSet += numbers;
    };

  for (let i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    _______________ Math.floor(Math.random() * length)
  }
  }
```

I'm not sure what else to put with the math.floor either.

Comment: Not an answer, but `key_strings.symbol` from your example needs to have some of those characters escaped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to concatenate the properties of `key_string` to `passwordCharSet`, not the response to the prompt.

When getting the random character, you need to index `passwordCharSet` and use `passwordCharSet.length`.

In `key_strings.symbol` you need to escape `"` and `\`.

```js
const key_strings = {
  lowercase: 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz',
  uppercase: 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ',
  number: '0123456789',
  symbol: "!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~",
};

function generatePassword() {
  var passwordCharSet = "";

  var length = window.prompt("Enter a number from 8 to 128 for password length.");

  var lowercase = window.confirm("Would you like to use lowercase letters?");
  if (lowercase) {
    passwordCharSet += key_strings.lowercase;
  };

  var uppercase = window.confirm("Would you like to use uppercase letters?");
  if (uppercase) {
    passwordCharSet += key_strings.uppercase;
  };

  var symbols = window.confirm("Would you like to use symbols?");
  if (symbols) {
    passwordCharSet += key_strings.symbol;
  };

  var numbers = window.confirm("Would you like to use numbers?");
  if (numbers) {
    passwordCharSet += key_strings.number;
  };
  var password = "";
  for (let i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    password += passwordCharSet[Math.floor(Math.random() * passwordCharSet.length)]
  }
  return password;
}

console.log(generatePassword());
```